Invalid credentials for docker postgress image
I am creating two databases: product, and test one:
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - postgres_test_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/create_script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_script.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  test-db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    volumes:
      - postgres_test_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/create_script.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_script.sql
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
volumes:
  postgres_prod_data:
  postgres_test_data:

This docker compose works, it created images, started containers.
However i when i try to conncet to db image, it says invalid credentials, HOWEVER when i try to connect to test-db which is literally copy paste with changed port, it WORKS.
What is causing this? These images are newly created, with new volumes and literally copy paste of each others, how come one works and one not?
Logs do not specify any error for neither of them.
Thanks for help

It looks like you're using the postgres_test_data volume in both your db and test-db containers. That's going to cause one of the services to fail to start.

db and test-db are using  the same volume, which might lead to inconsistencies .
Try using different volumes maybe that can resolve your issue.
Also make sure to reset Containers to ensure a fresh start:
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up

